# Absolute limit in Huffman encoding

Tags: cryptography, encryption

I have computed the average code length using the Huffman encoding. Now, I am asked to compare the average code length with Absolute limit but I ain't sure about the absolute limit here is :(
Could someone assist me here with the what the absolute limit ??

Comment: There are 5 symbols in for this task so is the absolute limit 5! .....is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Presumably the "absolute limit" is the entropy, but only you can say. It's not a standard term, as far as I know.

Comment: And entropy is a lower bound to the average codeword length for any code. Your 5! makes no sense to me.